# Tic Tac Toe draw function

Tags: javascript, html, button, tic-tac-toe

I have made a tic tac toe game with javascript.
I've got 2 questions. 
1. I want a "start" button. So you can only see/play the game if you clicked on the button.

And now the hardest:
If it is draw, then the computer have to reset 1 random square. The game continues as long as necessary,  until there is a winner.

```
function drawCheck() {
    vari()
    moveCount = sqr1T + sqr2T + sqr3T + sqr4T + sqr5T + sqr6T + sqr7T + sqr8T + sqr9T 
    if(moveCount == 9) {
        reset()
        alert ("draw!")
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

As for your first question, you need the following HTML code:

```
<button id="startbutton" onclick="startGame()">Start Game</button>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
function startGame() {
    //Get rid of the button
    document.getElementById('startbutton').style.display = 'none'
    //Start the game
}
```

For your second question, you need the following JavaScript:

```
//Generate random number from 1 to 9
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1
//Reset the square
if(random == 1) {
    sqr1T = 0
} else if(random == 2) {
    sqr2T = 0
} else if(random == 3) {
    sqr3T = 0
} else if(random == 4) {
    sqr4T = 0
} else if(random == 5) {
    sqr5T = 0
} else if(random == 6) {
    sqr6T = 0
} else if(random == 7) {
    sqr7T = 0
} else if(random == 8) {
    sqr8T = 0
} else if(random == 9) {
    sqr9T = 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment! I've got the start button, but the game is already there. The game have to show up when you clicked on the button. And what is the code to reset just one square?

Comment: 1. Display the game when the user clicks the button 2. Use a massive if statement: `if(random == 1) { sqr1T = 0}` and so on

Comment: You should really consider using arrays

Comment: Agreed. With an array you wouldn't have to have a massive if statement.